# 398 row datalist slowing down modal open?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ado.net

Hey guys I got a weird issue.. I have a datalist that's only loaded on pageload it contains 2 columns a name and date and has 398 rows.. In IE 7 and above(and prob previous version) when I open a modal via a button click it takes almost 5 seconds to open. HOWEVER, if I do not bind this datalist it's MUCH faster..

Also this is only happening in IE, Chrome, Firefox and opera both open the modal instantly with the datalist binded...

Josh

```
<asp:DataList ID="dListObitOneLiner" runat="server" style="margin-left:5px;" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="dListObitOneLiner_SelectedIndexChanged"
RepeatColumns="1" 
                DataKeyField="ObitId" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbObitOne" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("DeceasedName")%>'
                         CommandName="select"
                         Font-Names="Arial"
                         Font-Size="8pt"
                         ForeColor="Black"
                         Font-Bold="true"
                         Width="200px"
                         CssClass="MainSection_RecentObits_DataList">
                     </asp:LinkButton>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceDateTime")%>'
                        Font-Names="Arial"
                         Font-Size="8pt"
                         ForeColor="Black"
                         Font-Bold="true"
                         Width="125px"
                         CssClass="MainSection_RecentObits_DataList"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="Arial" />
            </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: What's the html you render around your list, and is it slow if you skip all surrouding html?

Comment: Mikael, I edited my post.. Inside the Itemtemplate as you can see there's only 2 controls, the list is surrounded by a container div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found the problem, IE isn't the quickest at rendering 398 link buttons, I had to go to a paging option and limit the number of item templates.